# Find within the first 10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to screen-scrape contents of a website.

I set `fetch_number` to specify the number of `<divs>` that I want to retrieve. For example, I may want the `first(10)` tweets from the target page.

The code looks like this:

```
doc.css(".tweet").first(fetch_number).each do |item|
  title = item.css("a")[0]['title']
end
```

However, when there is less than 10 matching `div` tags returned, it will report

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'css' for nil:NilClass
```

This is because, when no matching HTML is found, it will return nil.

How can I make it return all the available data within 10? I don't need the nils.

UPDATE:

```
task :test_fetch => :environment do
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'
  url = 'http://themagicway.taobao.com/search.htm?&search=y&orderType=newOn_desc'
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url) )
  puts doc.css(".main-wrap .item").count
  doc.css(".main-wrap .item").first(30).each do |item_info|
    if item_info
      href = item_info.at(".detail a")['href']
      puts href
    else
      puts 'this is empty'
    end
  end
end
```

Return resultes(Near the end):

```
24
http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=41249522884
http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=40369253621
http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=40384876796
http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=40352486259
http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=40384968205
.....
http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38843789106
http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38843517455
http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38854788276
http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38825442050
http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38630599372
http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38346270714
http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38357729988
http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38345374874
this is empty
this is empty
this is empty
this is empty
this is empty
this is empty
```

`count` reports only 24 elements, but it retuns a 30 array.
And it actually is not an array, but `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
title = item.css("a")[0]['title']
```

is a bad practice.

Instead, consider writing using [`at`](http://rdoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:at) or [`at_css`](http://rdoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:at_css) instead of [`search`](http://rdoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:search) or [`css`](http://rdoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:css):

```
title = item.at('a')['title']
```

Next, if the `<a>` tag returned doesn't have a `title` parameter, Nokogiri and/or Ruby will be upset because the `title` variable will be nil. Instead, improve your CSS selector to only allow matches like `<a title="foo">`:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<body><a href="foo">foo</a><a href="bar" title="bar">bar</a></body>')
doc.at('a').to_html # => "<a href=\"foo\">foo</a>"
doc.at('a[title]').to_html # => "<a href=\"bar\" title=\"bar\">bar</a>"
```

Notice how the first, which is not constrained to look for tags with a `title` parameter returns the first `<a>` tag. Using `a[title]` will only return ones with a `title` parameter.

That means your loop over the values will never return nil, and you won't have a problem needing to `compact` them out of the returned array.

As a general programming tip, if you're getting nils like that, look at the code generating the array, because odds are good it's not doing it right. You should *ALWAYS* know what sort of results your code will generate. Using `compact` to clean up the array is a knee-jerk reaction to not having written the code correctly most of the time.

---

Here's your updated code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
url = 'http://themagicway.taobao.com/search.htm?&search=y&orderType=newOn_desc'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url) )
puts doc.css(".main-wrap .item").count
doc.css(".main-wrap .item").first(30).each do |item_info|
  if item_info
    href = item_info.at(".detail a")['href']
    puts href
  else
    puts 'this is empty'
  end
end
```

And here's what's wrong:

```
doc.css(".main-wrap .item").first(30)
```

Here's a simple example demonstrating why that doesn't work:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
<body>
<p>foo</p>
</body>
</html>
EOT
```

In Nokogiri, `search',`css`and`xpath` are equivalent, except that the first is generic and can take either CSS or XPath, while the last two are specific to that language.

```
doc.search('p') # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcf360ef750 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcf360ef4f8 "foo">]>]
doc.search('p').size # => 1
doc.search('p').map(&:to_html) # => ["<p>foo</p>"]
```

That shows that the NodeSet returned by doing a simple `search` returns only one node, and what the node looks like.

```
doc.search('p').first(2) # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe3a28d2848 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe3a28c7b50 "foo">]>, nil]
doc.search('p').first(2).size # => 2
```

Searching using `first(n)` returns "n" elements. If that many aren't found Nokogiri fills them in using nil values.

This is counter what we'd assume `first(n)` to do, since [`Enumerable#first`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-first) returns up-to-n and won't pad with nils. This isn't a bug, but it is unexpected behavior since Enumerable's `first` sets the expected behavior for methods with that name, but, this is [`NodeSet#first`](http://rdoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#first-instance_method), not `Enumerable#first`, so it does what it does until the Nokogiri authors change it. (You can see why it happens if you look at the source for that particular method.)

Instead, slicing the NodeSet *does* show the expected behavior:

```
doc.search('p')[0..1] # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe3a28d2848 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe3a28c7b50 "foo">]>]
doc.search('p')[0..1].size # => 1

doc.search('p')[0, 2] # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe3a28d2848 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe3a28c7b50 "foo">]>]
doc.search('p')[0, 2].size # => 1
```

So, don't use `NodeSet#first(n)`, use the slice form `NodeSet#[]`.

Applying that, I'd write the code something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

URL = 'http://themagicway.taobao.com/search.htm?&search=y&orderType=newOn_desc'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL))

hrefs = doc.css(".main-wrap .item .detail a[href]")[0..29].map { |anchors|
  anchors['href']
}

puts hrefs.size
puts hrefs
# >> 24
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=41249522884
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=40369253621
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=40384876796
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=40352486259
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=40384968205
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=40384816312
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=40384600507
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=39973451949
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=39861209551
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=39545678869
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=39535371171
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=39509186150
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38973412667
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38910499863
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38942960787
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38910403350
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38843789106
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38843517455
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38854788276
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38825442050
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38630599372
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38346270714
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38357729988
# >> http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=38345374874
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope I can accept 2 answers at the same time. Very helpful!

Comment: The real problem is that. I want to get 20 items of a page. So I write a selector with `first(20)`. However, it may just have 15 items. So the remaining of the 20-array would have 15 items + 5 nil. I don't feel like this could be improved by using a better selector, but to change the `first(20)` into a more proper way. But I don't know how.

Comment: `[].first(2) # => []`. You can't get "15 + 5 nil" unless you're processing the array incorrectly, you'd only get 15. A better selector *will* help; This is based on a lot of experience processing sites. So, the problem isn't in how you're requesting 20, it's what you're doing afterwards.

Comment: see my update. The rest empty array is what I'm getting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
doc.css(".tweet").first(fetch_number).each do |item|
  title = item.css("a")[0]['title'] rescue nil
end
```

And let me know it works or not? It will not show error

Comment: hmm or just `title = item.css("a")[0]['title'] if item`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just ommited the first and last line of your answer in my comment. Of course my line should go inbetween them.

Answer (score 1):

Try `compact`.

`[1, nil, 2, nil, 3] # => [1, 2, 3]`

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-compact

(ie: `first(fetch_number).compact.each do |item|`)

Comment: Using `compact` is a bandaid to patch the real problem, which is not using an adequate selector. Fix the selector and the nils will go away, removing the need to use `compact`.